# How to get row data in columns and column data in rows using pivot in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current result which I am getting from my stored procedure:

[image]

Expected result from current result:

[image]

Comment: I've seen link only answers, a link only question is new. Please edit your question to describe your problem, describe your schema, show your code and sample data

Comment: Oh man I lolled =) a photo of a piece of paper with requirements, that has to be a first in SO.

Comment: Now I'm imaging you taking a photo of the answer that suits you most, to type out at work =). In any case, GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Union all with Pivot..

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0d07/1)

```
declare @table table
(period nvarchar(10),num int,cost int,value int)
insert into @table
select 'Jan-16',1,100,100 
union all select 'Feb-16',2,200,200 
union all select 'Mar-16',3,300,300
union all select 'Apr-16',4,400,400 
union all select 'May-16',5,500,500 
union all select 'Jun-16',6,600,600 
union all select 'Jul-16',7,700,700 
union all select 'Aug-16',8,800,800 
union all select 'Sep-16',9,900,900 
union all select 'Oct-16',10,1000,1000 
union all select 'Nov-16',11,1100,1100 
union all select 'Dec-16',12,1200,1200 


--select * from @table 

select 'No of Order' as Period,[Jan-16], [Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16],[May-16],[Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16],[Dec-16]
from 
(
select period,num from @table) u 
pivot  ( sum(num) for period in ([Jan-16] ,[Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16], [May-16], [Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16], [Dec-16]))
as pvt

union all
select 'Cost Of Order' as Period,[Jan-16], [Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16],[May-16],[Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16],[Dec-16]
from 
(
select period,cost from @table) u 
pivot  ( sum(Cost) for period in ([Jan-16] ,[Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16], [May-16], [Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16], [Dec-16]))
as pvt

union all
select 'Value Of Order' as Period,[Jan-16], [Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16],[May-16],[Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16],[Dec-16]
from 
(
select period,value from @table) u 
pivot  ( sum(value) for period in ([Jan-16] ,[Feb-16],[Mar-16],[Apr-16], [May-16], [Jun-16],[Jul-16],[Aug-16],[Sep-16],[Oct-16],[Nov-16], [Dec-16]))
as pvt
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: You can perhaps do something like this? UNION ALL, case etc etc]
An  image only answer to an image only question!

Comment: do u have done any query related to the scenario..then plz share

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) As AverageCost 
From Production.Product
Group by DaysToManufacture


Here is the result set.
DaysToManufacture          AverageCost
0                          5.0885
1                          223.88
2                          359.1082
4                          949.4105
```

No products are defined with three DaysToManufacture.

The following code displays the same result, pivoted so that the DaysToManufacture values become the column headings. A column is provided for three [3] days, even though the results are NULL.

-- Pivot table with one row and five columns

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Here is the result set.

```
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days    0         1         2           3       4       
AverageCost                       5.0885    223.88    359.1082    NULL    949.4105
```

Answer (score 0):

My Example:

```
DECLARE 
@v_Columns VARCHAR(MAX),
@v_StartDate DATETIME = '09/15/2015',
@v_EndDate DATETIME = '12/15/2020',
@v_Query VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @v_Columns = COALESCE(@v_Columns,'[') + convert(varchar, Date, 101) + '],[' 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM view_wc_sessions_info) th
WHERE
th.Date BETWEEN @v_StartDate AND @v_EndDate

SET @v_Columns = SUBSTRING(@v_Columns, 1, LEN(@v_Columns)-2)

SET @v_Query = 

'SELECT
*
FROM
(
 select [Total], Date, fk_student_rcid
  from view_WC_SESSIONS_Info th
WHERE
th.Date BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @v_StartDate, 101) + '''
AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @v_EndDate, 101) + '''
) src
PIVOT
(
COUNT(src.[Total])
FOR src.Date IN (' + @v_Columns + ')
) AS pivotview'

EXEC(@v_Query)
```